# I can't trust USB pendrive finished copy in Ubuntu 1404

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive

How can I really know that Ubuntu 14.04 finished copying in my USB pendrive that does not have an activity led?

For example, I connect it to the USB 3 port (pendrive is USB 3) then it shows like it finished copying (100% then dialog closes). After 2 mins and when I put the pendrive in another PC, a warning shows up in Ubuntu that it couldn't finish copying, and the file was corrupted in my pendrive.

So, is there a way to actually trust Ubuntu when it says that it finished copying something?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-copying what you have on the pen drive. Hopefully that will work. Now your question how can I tell if it's done? Assuming you have ubuntu go to the GNOME-System_Monitor and go to the Procceses tab, and when your copying the files the nautilis file manager might be on the top. When it goes down back then the files have probably been copied. Another way is to go under the Performance tab. When you are coping the files the disk might go up on the graph. But when it goes down it is probably done. Finally you can copy the files via terminal. Go to your GNOME-Terminal and type in this command.

cp (File being copied) (Destination folder)

when it is done you will see something like this

nicholas@nicholas-desktop:~$

Also the drive or the drive writer might be corrupted.
In that case you might have to buy a new drive or use a different drive port on your computer.